# Remote Desktop switches to Chinese on ctrl+space

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, remote-desktop, chinese

I have Windows XP on my laptop and use Remote Desktop Connection to work on a computer with Windows Vista. On my laptop I use 3 languages: English, Russian, Chinese. I switch between them by Alt+Shift, changing to Chinese with Ctrl+Space is disabled. On the remote computer there is only one Language on the Installed services list - English. For some reason, when I press Ctrl+Sapce on that computer (e.g. for autocomplete in NetBeans) it switches to Chinese (language bar at the bottom shows 'CH') and I cannot input anything. This never happened until today (before I worked on that computer from my laptop without any problems).

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPD: in Advanced Key Settings there is no action for Ctrl+Space on both computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the windows default. CRTL+SPC = Turn Chinese IME on 101 keyboard on or off

You can change the key combination for switching between languages or keyboard layouts in the Advanced Key Setting dialog box. To open the Advanced Key Setting dialog box, right-click the Language bar, and then click Settings. Under Preferences, click Key Settings.

Put another shortcut instead of CRTL+SPC. Then you can use CRTL+SPC as you wish.

Comment: I have already tried to check that. The problem is that there is no action for Ctrl+Space in the Advanced Key Setting dialog box at all.

Comment: Then regedit that. HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Input Method/Hot Keys

00000070 for the Chinese (Traditional) IME - Ime/NonIme Toggle hotkey
00000010 for the Chinese (Simplified) IME - Ime/NonIme Toggle hotkey Just remove those.